# How to make a discord bot stop spamming when it is spamming in discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

How can I make a discord bot **stop** spamming when it is spamming in discord py (**the same bot**)?

I have made my discord bot that can spam, but I can't stop the bot from spamming when it is already spamming... how do you do it? can anyone help me?

```
@bot.command(name="spam", help="spam some message")
async def spam(ctx, times:int, *, message):
  for i in range(times):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Comment: you can use a `global` flag variable which can be set by another cmd (maybe `stopspam`) and check that here (`spam()`) to break your `for loop` of `spam()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `global` flag variable which can be set by another command (called below as `stopspam yes`) to stop the spam messages.

Please find the full implementation below,

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # create the global spam stop flag
    # and set False
    global stop_spam_flag
    stop_spam_flag = False
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.command(name="spam", help="spam some message")
async def spam(ctx, times:int, *, message):
    # get the global flag into this function
    global stop_spam_flag
    for i in range(times):
        await ctx.send(message)
        # check the global flag here
        if stop_spam_flag:
            break
    # reset the flag
    stop_spam_flag = False

@bot.command(name="stopspam", help="stops the spam messages")
async def stopspam(ctx, *, message):
    # get the global flag
    global stop_spam_flag
    if message == 'yes':
        # set the global flag
        stop_spam_flag = True

bot.run('TOKEN HERE!)
```